# Lexis function not found in R

Tags: r

I am using this code from the R help guide in the Epi 
package:

```
# A small bogus cohort
xcoh <- structure( list( id = c("A", "B", "C"),
                  birth = c("14/07/1952", "01/04/1954", 
"10/06/1987"),
                  entry = c("04/08/1965", "08/09/1972", 
"23/12/1991"),
                   exit = c("27/06/1997", "23/05/1995", 
"24/07/1998"),
                   fail = c(1, 0, 1) ),
                 .Names = c("id", "birth", "entry", "exit", 
"fail"),
              row.names = c("1", "2", "3"),
                  class = "data.frame" )

# Define a Lexis object with timescales calendar time and 
age 
Lcoh <- Lexis( entry = list( per=entry ),
            exit = list( per=exit,
                         age=exit-birth ),
     exit.status = fail,
            data = xcoh )
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in Lexis(entry = list(per = entry), exit = list(per = exit, age = exit -  : 
could not find function "Lexis"
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: try `epi::Lexis`? or check that you've spelled it right?

Comment: Did you include `library(Epi)` in your code?

Comment: @DC2. Did the solution work ? Was in the problem with not using install.packages()

Answer (score 0):

Epi package first needs to be installed in the environment using:

```
install.packages("Epi")
```

And then the library for Epi needs to be loaded.

```
library(Epi)
```

Hence your code being modified as follows:

```
install.packages("Epi")
library(Epi)

xcoh <- structure( list( id = c("A", "B", "C"),
                         birth = c("14/07/1952", "01/04/1954", 
                                   "10/06/1987"),
                         entry = c("04/08/1965", "08/09/1972", 
                                   "23/12/1991"),
                         exit = c("27/06/1997", "23/05/1995", 
                                  "24/07/1998"),
                         fail = c(1, 0, 1) ),
                   .Names = c("id", "birth", "entry", "exit", 
                              "fail"),
                   row.names = c("1", "2", "3"),
                   class = "data.frame" )

# Define a Lexis object with timescales calendar time and 

Lcoh <- Lexis( entry = list( per=entry ),
               exit = list( per=exit,
                            age=exit-birth ),
               exit.status = fail,
               data = xcoh )
```

**Note:** I have removed the line that says `age`. Assuming it is not relevant to the question posted here.